# How can I get rid of trailing spaces in vim without breaking &?

Tags: vim

I read [the wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces) and put this in my vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType less,sass,yml,css,html,php,twig autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> :%s/\s\+$//e
```

Now the problem is whenever I save `&` is broken: it repeats a mix of the last substitution and the substitution. If for instance, I do `:s/foo/bar` and then save,`&` seems to do `:s/foo//`. I'd like it to do `:s/foo/bar/`. How can I restore this functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `:%s...` portion of your auto command to this:

```
:call setline(1, map(getline(1,'$'), 'substitute(v:val,"\\s\\+$","","")'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! [adopted!](https://github.com/greg0ire/dotfiles/commit/932268c9074699d6c1afe48df21db768ad39942e)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to avoid using `:substitute`, as there's currently no easy way to save and restore the last substitute string; the `:help function-undo-search` doesn't help here.

Most of the plugins (as shown on the referenced Wiki page) also suffer from this problem. A workaround would be using `call setline(substitute(getline(lnum)), '\s\+$', '', '')` in a loop over all lines, but that's probably much slower than the `:substitute`.

Comment: I probably won't accept your answer, but +1, it is very informative.